# Ant JUnit task Can't Load junit/framework/TestCase.class

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, junit

I have an ant project that I included a junit test task.  I set the classpath up correctly to include the junit jar and my built classes and jar.  However, when I run the test task and set the output to debug, it states that "Couldn't find junit/framework/TestCase.class"

Here is my test task:

```
  <target name="test" >
    <junit printsummary="yes" fork="true" haltonfailure="yes" >
        <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
        <test name="mytest.MyTest" haltonfailure="no" />            
    </junit>
</target>
```

Here is where my classpath.test is defined:

```
<path id="classpath.test">
    <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.10.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="build/jar/MyJar.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${build.test.dir}" />
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <path refid="build.classpath"/>
</path>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: test name="mytest.MyTest"? And your error message says "Couldn't find junit/framework/TestCase.class". Which is it, MyTest or TestCase?

Comment: mytest.MyTest extends TestCase.class.  That is needed for the ant task pick it up as a junit test.

Comment: Could you please post the output of Ant that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

junit/framework/TestCase.class specifies a JUnit 3.x test class and you have set your classpath with JUnit 4.10

You either need to convert your test to use JUnit 4.x or update your classpath to include JUnit 3.x jar instead of JUnit 4.10 jar.